# Сохранение excel файла

Tags: c#, excel

Не могу понять как правильно сохранить файл, чтобы в нем остались изменения.

```
var outbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Range _excelCells1 = (Excel.Range)outbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A1", "J1"].Cells;
_excelCells1.Merge(Type.Missing);
outbook.ActiveSheet.Range[_excelCells1].Value = "Табель учета рабочего времени с "
     + RTime(Convert.ToDateTime(arrData[2, 16].ToString().Substring(3, 11).Replace(".", "-")),
     arrData[2, 16].ToString().Substring(17, 2));
int k = 0;
k += 1;
outbook.ActiveSheet.Range["A2"].Value = k;
outbook.SaveAs(dir + "\\Parse.xlsx"); 
outbook.Close();
```

На текущий момент файл создается, однако текст, который должен был сохранится в объединенную ячейку туда не сохранился, но остальная информация сохранилась.В чем может быть проблема и как это исправить.

Comment: 1) Замените `outbook.ActiveSheet` на `outbook.Sheets(1)`. 2) `outbook.Application.Visible`. 3) *как можно создать объединенную ячейку с данными* Выполните в Excel руками при включённом макрорекордере. *как менять номер строки без заранее созданного счетчика, т.е. "A2", "A3","A4"* `ForEach oneCell In Range`.

Comment: Файлы Excel все в формате xlsx? Если да, то выкиньте интеропт и используйте EpPlus.

Comment: @Akina, при замене ActiveSheet на Sheets(1), происходит ошибка CS1955 Невызываемый член "_Workbook.Sheets" не может использоваться как метод и не могли бы Вы привести пример использования ForEach oneCell In Range

Comment: @Akina, при использовании outbook.Application.Visible файл открывается и мгновенно закрывается. Я пробовал убирать закрытие файла, но это не помогло. Как тогда можно добиться того, чтобы файл не закрывался мгновенно?

Comment: *при замене ActiveSheet на Sheets(1), происходит ошибка* См. встроеную справку Excel, статья "Workbook.Sheets Property". *пример использования ForEach oneCell In Range* Там же, "For Each...Next Statement" и "Worksheet.Range Property". И вообще посмотреть объектную модель Excel будет полезно. *Как тогда можно добиться того, чтобы файл не закрывался мгновенно?* А нафига?